# Conditional Sylesheets Rails 3.1

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, stylesheet

I am in the process of cross browser testing my site and of course IE is giving me the biggest headache. I know I have to use conditional style sheets but am unsure of where to put these in rails so they are rendered only if IE7 or IE8 for example. I have seen a example on stack overflow but he seems to be using HAML whereas I am not.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and if so what did you do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the asset pipeline, the only solution I've found for this so far is to not include your stylesheets so that they get compiled into the one file, but instead just include your IE stylesheet(s) separately in the `head` tag of your layout file as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, so just to confirm, place my stylesheet as normal in Assets/stylesheets ( called ie7.css for example), dont include it in the stylesheet_link_tag, place [if IE 7] syntax for example in views/layouts/application?

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>

<!--[if IE 7]>
<link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
<link href="ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

</head>
```